# CakePHP sending POST data

Tags: cakephp, post

Inside my CakePHP 2.4 application I need to send `POST` headers inside my response.
It seems like Cakeresponse can send headers with the response:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakeresponse

Is there a similar way to put `POST` data inside response ?

Comment: send POST on the response?? it's not possible.. it doesn't make sense... maybe you could explain us a little more what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: Data passed through a form in CakePHP is POST by default, are you receiving your data from an external source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending POST data without a form is mentioned here:
[Sending POST data without form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780912/sending-post-data-without-form)
and here
[POST without Form Method (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753589/post-without-form-method-php)

But an AJAX solution is not suitable for me. I solved problem with sending data with headers. I created my own headers, added them to current headers and send data.